# LongForm labels appear inline but on one line instead of two

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a longer label display inline with a textbox. I want the label to be on one line and display inline with the textbox. I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. Here is some example code:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="d" class="control-label col-sm-2"> Two line label here:</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
  <input type="text" placeholder="" required="true" name="p" id="d" class="form-control" title="">
 </div>
</div>
```

What classes should I be using to do this?

Comment: RTFM: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal read and learn, please

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this way..

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Two line label here</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount"/>

</div>
```